# Binding events to entities in crafty.js

Tags: javascript, craftyjs

I am currently trying to learn how to use crafty.js to create games. Right now the square sprite is drawn, but I am unable to get it to do anything. Here is the code for my game:

```
Game = {
  // Initialize our game
  start: function() {
    // Start crafty and set a background color
    Crafty.init(640, 480);
    Crafty.background('green');
    Crafty.sprite(16, "assets/square.png", {square:[0,0]});
    Crafty.c('SquareControls', {
             init: function() {

               this.bind('enterframe', function() {
                 this.x = this.x+2;
               });

             return this;
           }
         });

    //// SCENES ////
    Crafty.scene("main", function() {
      var square = Crafty.e("2D, Canvas, square, SquareControls")
                         .attr({x:32, y:32, width:16, height:16});
    });

    Crafty.scene("main");
  } // end start()
} // end Game class
```

Answer (score 1):

Event names are case sensitive. You misspelled the **EnterFrame** event.

```
this.bind('EnterFrame', function() {
    this.x = this.x+2;
});
```